# Why does MPI_Recv fail when there is an accumulation of MPI_Send calls

Tags: c++, out-of-memory, mpi

I have an MPI program in which worker ranks (rank != 0) make a bunch of MPI_Send calls, and the master rank (rank == 0) receives all these messages. However, I run into a Fatal error in MPI_Recv - MPI_Recv(...) failed, Out of memory.

Here is the code that I am compiling in Visual Studio 2010.
I run the executable like so:

mpiexec -n 3 MPIHelloWorld.exe

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int numprocs, rank, namelen, num_threads, thread_id;
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &namelen);

    if(rank == 0){
        for(int k=1; k<numprocs; k++){
            for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++){
                double x;
                MPI_Recv(&x, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, k, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++){
            double x = 5;
            MPI_Send(&x, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }
}
```

If I run with only 2 processes, the program does not crash. So it seems like the problem is when there is an accumulation of the MPI_Send calls from a third rank (aka a second worker node).

If I decrease the number of iterations to 100,000 then I can run with 3 processes without crashing. However, the amount of data being sent with one million iterations is ~ 8 MB (8 bytes for double * 1000000 iterations), so I don't think the "Out of Memory" is referring to any physical memory like RAM.

Any insight is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: For that particular question it is extremely important to know which MPI implementation you are using and in what configuration.

Comment: Using MS-MPI v 7.1 on Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MPI_send` operation stores the data on the [system buffer](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi_performance/) ready to send. The size of this buffer and where it is stored is [implementation specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27008373/what-is-difference-between-application-buffer-and-system-buffer#27017669) (I remember hearing that this can even be in the interconnects). In my case (linux with mpich) I don't get a memory error. One way to explicitly change this buffer is to use `MPI_buffer_attach` with `MPI_Bsend`. There may also be a way to change the system buffer size (e.g. `MP_BUFFER_MEM` system variable on IBM systems).

However that this situation of unrequited messages should probably not occur in practice. In your example above, the order of the `k` and `i` loops could be swapped to prevent this build up of messages.

Comment: thanks for the info about the system buffer. I tried switching the order of the k and i loops however, and the behavior of the program remained the same.

Comment: From here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg243459(v=ws.11).aspx#MSMPI  it looks like MS-MPI doesn't offer any control over setting the system buffer size.